# Displaying the wiki content dynamically beside each image

Tags: tableau-api

I want to display images of 10 people on my dashboard, when i hover the image dynamically it needs to display a wiki page to the side of each image related to that person, how do i achieve this in tableau?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps after you have a dashboard with your people on one of the charts. My example uses the pesticide list from the most recent #makeovermonday.

In your dashboard, drag the web page object in.
[image: web page object]

Click the option dropdown of that new object and click `Add URL Action`.
[image]

In the popup place the main portion of your wikipedia url in the box and select your people field which will become the dynamic portion of the URL. Mine is pesticides.
[image]

Change `Run action on` to `Hover`
[image]

Now when you hover on your main chart it will update the web page object with the person hovered on. I just hovered on Atrazine in this image
[image]

You will probably have to update your people names to make sure they match wikipedia's url.